# How access Azure Active Directory (Users/Groups) through rest api using C#?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm new to Azure and also Azure Active Directory, I'm not familiar with Azure environment but I got enough credentials.

Can anyone help me with my first api call for Azure using C# console application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example of what you have tried, and where you are having issues?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started is to take a look at our open source samples available on GitHub.

Here is a good one for your needs: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console

You should follow the instructions which are written in the ReadMe, and it should walk you through the application registration process and getting the application up and running. The application itself should make a number of queries to the Azure Active Directory Graph API.

You can find all of those queries here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/GraphRequests.cs

I hope this helps you with your first application!